# Visiting the UK as a tourist and later returning to UK

Tags: uk, argentina, repeat-visits

I'm from Argentina wanting to joining my girlfriend who will be studying for one year in Edinburgh. As an Argentine I don't need any particular permit to go to UK as a tourist. The permit of stay is for a maximum of 6 months.

But what if after the 6 months I go to *e.g. Spain* for one month and then return to the UK - does the tourist 6 month permit start running again?

Is there a minimum period of time for which you have to be out of the UK so as the tourist permit starts running again?

I'm only considering the option of leaving to somewhere in Europe.

Comment: yooo im eric from taiwan,my plan is also to live( travel) in the UK within 6 months.may i ask you document question please??
2. could i use a train ticket to france or plane ticket to france rather than a return ticket to taiwan ??
    3. my real plan is to be a nomad in the UK, but i dont want to complicate things for the officer in the airport, could i just simply my schedule ( pretend as a one month travel in the UK??
4. how could i prepare the accomodation prove if i am going to use couchsurfing for 80 percent of the time while staying in the uk?? thank you so much for helping meee~~

Answer (score 2):

There is no formal limit, but Border agents have discretion whether to admit you. If they think that you are living in the UK with your girlfriend and pretending to be a tourist, they will not admit you. In my experience the border agents are reasonable, but they are not stupid.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I wouldn't be leaving with her. It's true.,the story must sound believable and reasonable. Anyway, I MUST return once my scholarship finishes, so i guess that helps the story.